# Custom entity creation (construction) in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have Order class and SubOrder: Order descendant. Now, Order has .Item and SubOrder (obviously) has it, too, but SubOrder needs SubItem to be there. Which is easy when created:

```
Item = new SubItem((ISomeInterface)this);
```

but how do I tell NHibernate to create SubItem instead of Item when it **loads** SubOrder from database (Session.Get<SubOrder>(id))? The type of the item is not in the database (and I don't need and don't want it to be there); it's always "Item for Order, SubItem for SubOrder". Moreover, it needs to be created with (ISomeInterface)SubOrder as constructor parameter.

In short, how do I manage custom entity create in NHibernate to achieve things described above? Is it possible to have a reference to SubOrder when creating SubItem (I can live with property "injection" if not)?

I can probably use IUserType but it seems to be an overkill; and I don't see how to apply IUserType to SubOrder.Item only (same for IInterceptor). Also I don't see how to get a reference to the parent order, except to use OnLoad event for the SubOrder and set SubItem properties there... which is awkward.

Comment: I don't understand.  Is SubItem not mapped as an subclass of Item in your NHibernate mappings?

Comment: Yes it is not mapped. As I said I don't want to map it, because this means additional field in database - while this is purely static information already available to the program (Order->Item, SubOrder->SubItem). I _can_ live with mapping if I can to - but I'd like to do it without extra fields to overcome some software limitations.

Answer (score 0):

"OnLoad event for the SubOrder and set SubItem properties there" -> there's one solution.

Otherwise you could try writing a [custom ReflectionOptimizer](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/12/12/entities-behavior-injection.aspx).